# How to manage MediaPlayer Properly in jetpack compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Whenever i want to navigate to other screen i want my MediaPlayer should Stop where is best place to using the stop() function .

```
@Composable
 fun MenuScreen(navController: NavController) {

val context = LocalContext.current
val menuMusic : MediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context , R.raw.menu_music)
menuMusic.isLooping = true
menuMusic.start()

Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .background(color = darkBackground)
) {...}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your MediaPlayer to start when your composable enters the composition and stop when it leaves the composition, you would do this:

```
val context = LocalContext.current
val menuMusic: MediaPlayer = remember { 
    MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.menu_music) 
}

DisposableEffect(Unit) {
    menuMusic.isLooping = true
    menuMusic.start()

    onDispose {
        menuMusic.stop()
    }
}
```